# How the elements are stored in bit-field

Tags: c, bit-fields

Recently i faced a problem with bit fields

```
union u
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char x : 2;
        unsigned int y : 2;
    }p;
    int x;
};
int main()
{
    union u u = { 2 };
    printf("%d\n", u.p.x);
}
```

Its printing 2 actually as per the little endian rule. bitfield y should be assigned 2 
why 2 is assigned to x

Comment: Have you tried `printf("%zu\n", sizeof u);`? What does that tell you about `unsigned char x : 2;` and `unsigned int y : 2;`? It has nothing to do with endianness.

Comment: What do you imagine the "little endian rule" to be?

Comment: size is 8 how ?. As char is 1 byte and int is 4 . It looks like structure padding is coming in picture even if bitfields are used.

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
union u u = { 2 };
```

you are actaully assigning the member `u.p.x` as it is the first member of `struct p` according to

> When initializing a union, the initializer list must have only one member, which initializes the first member of the union unless a designated initializer is used (since C99). [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization)

if you want initialize `u.p.y` use:

```
union u u =  { {.y = 2} };
```

or

```
union u ux = { .p={ 0,2 } };
```